# How can i Get The result information in table with index

Tags: php

I have this code

```
foreach($GetJobResult->Components->Component as $component_index=>$component) {
   $quote_title= ($component_index+1).') '.$component->Title."\n";
   //var_dump($component_index+1);
   //die();

   if(isset($component->Paper->Family)) {
      if(isset($component->Paper->Type) && isset($component->Paper->Color)) {
         $getPaperInfoResult=$ws->getPaperInfo($component->Paper->Family,$component->Paper->Type);

         $quote_desc = $getPaperInfoResult->PapFamType[$component_index+1]->Lfam.' - '.$getPaperInfoResult->PapFamType[$component_index+1]->Lcoul.' - '.$getPaperInfoResult->PapFamType[$component_index+1]-> Gramm.' g/m2'."\n";
         var_dump($quote_desc); 
      }
   }
}
```

How can I stock the `$quote_desc` on table with index to get all information?
when I output `var_dump($quote_desc);` I have three lines but when I affected to variable I found just the last line.

```
var_dump($quote_desc);
string 'CouchÃ© Moderne Mat - IVOIRE NATUREL - 250 g/m2' (length=48)
string 'CouchÃ© Moderne Mat - BLANC - 350 g/m2' (length=39)
string 'ADHESIF BRILLANT - BLANC - 80 g/m2'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post var_dump($quote_desc);

Comment: string 'CouchÃ© Moderne Mat - IVOIRE NATUREL - 250 g/m2
' (length=48)

string 'CouchÃ© Moderne Mat - BLANC - 350 g/m2
' (length=39)

string 'ADHESIF BRILLANT - BLANC - 80 g/m2

Comment: @test please edit your question, do not add code in the comments

Comment: ok i added to my question the var_dump i need to put in table and get each one for example tab[1]= i get first sentences tab[2] = i get seconde sentences

Comment: sounds like $quote_desc is returning an array and you need to further loop through $quote_desc with another foreach

Comment: can you tell me by code because  i am not understand tahnks